# What does placing a @ in front of a C# variable name do?

Tags: c#

I've been working with some C# legacy code and I've been seeing a lot of @ symbols in front of variable names. What does this signify or do?

Currently I'm seeing it a lot in front of variables with common names that aren't reserved. E.g.:

```
MyProcedure(@step.LoadInstanceId, @step.ResultCode, @step.StatusCode);
```

Given that step isn't a reserved word, is there any reason that they should be escaped?

Comment: show us some examples. Are they reserved words like @public or just variable names like @weddingDate?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

It's just a way to allow declaring reserved keywords as vars.

```
void Foo(int @string)
```

Comment: That makes sense, but can you think of any reason why people would be putting them in front of non-keyword variable names -- other than the original developer being stupid?

Comment: My guess is that the previous coder didn't know how they worked.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to be sure, like doubly extra sure! In case the variable suddenly turns into a reserved keyword!

Comment: Maybe he came from a VB background where Step really IS a keyword.

Comment: @ripper: holy crap, why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: No sane coder under normal circumstances. What are some bizzare circumstances? When auto-generating code based on some ruleset, and not wanting to have a special case for reserved words.

Comment: @skaffman: Lots of things generate C# code, like ORM tools.

Comment: Interestingly, you don't need to use the @ can be omitted when using the variable.

  int @foo = 3;
  Console.WriteLine(foo);
  int bar = 4;
  Console.WriteLine(@bar);

Comment: I actually have seen resharper do this.  After refactor/extract method: @group.Properties.PropertyNames

Comment: I believe it is when a class must mirror some external schema. If the external schema has a field called "class" the mirrored class could call it's property @class.

Comment: `can you think of any reason why people would be putting them in front of non-keyword variable names -- other than the original developer being stupid?` - leftovers from automatical rename?

Comment: Another use-case for `@` annotation  would be for demonstration purposes in pseudo codes, specially when the code is long enough to confuse.

Comment: Some people must see some internal beauty of this syntax. A co-worker uses a lot of code like this pattern: @__foo .

Comment: I sometimes use `@this` in factory methods, makes things readable.

Answer (score 41):

It allows you to use a reserved word, like 'public' for example, as a variable name.

```
string @public = "foo";
```

I would not recommend this, as it can lead to unecessary confusion.

Answer (score 15):

Putting @ in front of a string tells the compuler not to process escape sequences found within the string.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx):

The advantage of @-quoting is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully qualified file name:

```
@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
```

To include a double quotation mark in an @-quoted string, double it:

```
@"""Ahoy!"" cried the captain." // "Ahoy!" cried the captain.
```

Another use of the @ symbol is to use referenced (/reference) identifiers that happen to be C# keywords. For more information, see [2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Variables, not string literals.

Comment: @Orion: yes it's also explained at the end ;-)

Comment: Once the string is in a variable it has already been escaped as it has to be parsed in order to be assigned to a variable so adding an @ to a string variable is not the same as adding it to a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

The @ sign is used with identifiers that are the same as language keywords. There are two main uses for this
 - interoperating with non-C# code. In languages like VB or IronPython the keywords are not the same as in C# and they may have declared classes and properties with names that match C# keywords. If this feature was not present this code would not be accessible in C#.
 - machine generated code. If a code generator generates code based on some external source (for example WSDL) the generator can just prefix all identifiers with @ and not check and convert identifiers that match C# keywords.

Are you sure that your case is not the second?

Answer (score 5):

This escapes reserved words in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The original question asks for a reason why one would escape a not-reserved word. What comes to my mind is that if `step` would become a reserved word in future the code example would still compile.  I guess it is also a valid option for code generators.