# What is the purpose of @ as part of a member name in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does placing a @ in front of a C# variable name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-variable-name-do)
>   [What’s the use/meaning of the @ character in variable names in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91817/whats-the-use-meaning-of-the-character-in-variable-names-in-c)

As you can imagine, Googling or Binging for any phrase containing an '@' is difficult.

In creating a new web service, one of the members of the imported C# proxy class is prefixed with the @.  For example:

```
plan.@event = new Insurance.Event();
```

I assume that it is Visual Studio's way resolving potential conflicts with reserved words because 'event' is a reserved word.  Changing the property in the web service interface to something other than 'event' (i.e. 'healthevent') removes the @ from the property.  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Jorn Interesting that SO didn't display the item that you cited as a possible related item when I crafted this question.

Comment: Well, the reason is probably the same as to why you did not find anything on Google/Bing. The title of this question and the one that I have linked really has no common keywords, except from `@` which is probably ignored by the search :)

Comment: Also, those comments are inserted automatically by SO's software when we select a close reason. I remembered a question like this recently; I didn't realize the one I recognized was itself a dupe of the one @Jorn found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. See [C# Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), [section 2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx) of the language specification, or [string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

From the keywords topic:

> Keywords are predefined, reserved
>   identifiers that have special meanings
>   to the compiler. They cannot be used
>   as identifiers in your program unless
>   they include @ as a prefix. For
>   example, @if is a valid identifier but
>   if is not because if is a keyword.

Comment: @Jeff:  Thanks for providing all of the links.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, names that conflict with C# keywords may be escaped with the @ character.

Comment: Actually all names may be preceded by the @ character, not only those that conflict with keywords.

Answer (score 5):

Yes that is correct.
You can use keywords as identifiers as long as you include @ as a prefix.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx for more info.