# How can i match all characters?

Tags: c#, regex, match

How can i match every possible character in regex.match for example.

```
string value4 = (",\"message\":\"all characters\",");
Match[] message = Regex.Matches(docText, @value4)
```

matched against

```
,"message":"all characters here",
```

I have tried

```
string value4 = (",\"message\":\".\","); 

string value4 = (",\"message\":\"[.]\","); 

string value4 = (",\"message\":\"[.*]\",");

string value4 = (",\"message\":\".*\",");
```

and none of them worked.

Edit:

the value that i'm matching against  `,"message":"all characters here",` can have any characters in the "all characters here" section, I would like to match all instances of `,"message":"all characters here",` ignoring what is in between the second set of quotes

Comment: What are you trying to do? By the way, In C#, `@value4` is the same as `value4`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-variable-name-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect any quotes in your value, you can use:

```
"message":"([^"]*)"
```

Which is written as

- `"\"message\":\"([^\"]*)\""` - as a regular string literal
- `@"""message"":""([^""]*)"""` as a [Verbatim String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0))

If you have escaped quotes, one option is this, which also allows all escaped characters:

```
"message":"(([^"\\]|\\.)*)"
```

Written as:

- `"\"message\":\"(([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\""`
- `@"""message"":""(([^""\\]|\\.)*)"""`

Comment: @user556396 - please edit that into the question, and explain what you're trying to do. I obviously misunderstood `:P`

Comment: Edited, hope that makes more sense

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for helping me out with that, the escape characters were preventing the match. Thanks.

Comment: @user556396 - No problem, happy to help. I was writing a short code example, but I guess you don't need it. There are oddities in the code - for example, `Regex.Matches` does not return an array, but a `MatchCollection` (though I assume that's just sample code). Anyway, good luck!