# What does '@' do in c#?

Tags: c#, syntax

I just went to write the line...

```
if (!e.PeriodicData.Keys.Contains(process))
{
}
```

but did a typo on "!" and hit "@" instead.  eg

```
if (@e.PeriodicData.Keys.Contains(process))
{
}
```

I was expecting intellisense to flipout but it didn't.  So I compiled and it compiled successfully.

Its not an [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28!_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28!%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), so what is "@"? What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case its a valid name. It is used if you want to use a keyword as a variable name like `@class`.

See: [What does placing a @ in front of a C# variable name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-variable-name-do)

Comment: That being said -- don't do this.  It's exceptionally confusing to use keywords as variable names.

Comment: In some cases its unavoidable - especially with MVC's HtmlHelpers that take HTML attributes.

Comment: An answer like this is a really good sign that you should have voted to close the question as a duplicate. I'm not really sure why you didn't; you don't seem to be adding any information beyond that given in the answers to the other question.

Answer (score 7):

In this case it is just getting the variable `e`. It is equivalent to `e`.

The `@` symbol before a var is used if you want to call a variable `class` for instance. To use reserved words as variables.

```
var @class = 1;
var @virtual = 2;
var @return = 3;
```

As for strings it uses the literal, for example:

```
"C:\\test\\example\\"
```

Is equivalent to

```
@"C:\test\example\"
```