# C# @ symbol in variable names

Tags: c#, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does placing a @ in front of a C# variable name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-variable-name-do)

Hi,

I justed picked up on Silverlight and RIA services. While creating a new domain service which supports editing, the following code was generated in the domain service class (C#):

```
  public void InsertClass(Class @class){
        ...
  }
```

What is the significance of the `@` symbol in the variable name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word in C# to denote a new type. You can't have a variable name that is a reserved word, so you use `@` to 'escape' the symbol.

AKA:

```
int int = 4; // Invalid
int @int = 4; // Valid
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@` is used in cases where you have to have a variable name that's also a c# reserved  keyword. In most cases it can be avoided (and should be, because of the confusion it can cause). Some times it's unavoidable; for instance in asp.net MVC you have add css class to an element you have to use an anonymous class like this

```
new {@class = "myCssClass" }
```

for it to render

```
... class="myCssClass" ...
```

There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

what would happen if you tried to name a variable `class`, do you think? The `@` prefix lets you use reserved/key words as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429529/what-does-the-symbol-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-c).

> The @ symbol allows you to use reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` sign is valid only at the beginning of a variable name and is used to allow reserved keywords to be used as variable names.

```
var @class = 12;  // This will compile
var cl@ss = 12; // This will NOT compile
```

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is used when you want to name variables that are also C# keywords.  i.e.,

var @abstract = "1234";

would create a string called "@abstract".  If you did not you would get a compile error.

Also - you can use the @ sign in front of strings:

var myStr = @"C:\MyDataFile.txt";

This way, you don't have to escape literals inside the string.  Normally you would have had to use a double \ after C: