# Visual studio C# packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

this is my problem with VS :S
in the first project :
`System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider obj;`
everything is ok
in the second project:
`System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider obj1;`
it doesn't recognize the AesCryptoServiceProvider?!!

is VS using different packages or what ?!

updated: changed the variable name but still not working

Comment: Are you including the references to the appropriate dll in each project?

Comment: @Jason no I didn't . but I didn't for both of the projects, how come one of them works yet the other doesn't !
what reference should I add ?

Comment: Both are using same .net version?

Comment: @AkashKava no. when I try to change the 2.0 .NET project to 4 , it gives more errors . how to overcome that ? and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if both projects are referencing `System.Core`. Probably only the first one has it. You've to add it on both to be able to use `AesCryptoServiceProvider`.

Moreover, as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) `AesCryptoServiceProvider` is only available since .NET 3.5. Check your project's properties, in particular the *Target Framework*.

Comment: it's a .net versions issue; the working one is 4 and the none working is 2 . can I add the references without changing the .net version? I did try to change it from 2 to 4 but it gave more errors in reference . and thanks for your help :D .

Comment: You've to change it to .NET 3.5 or higher otherwise you won't have access to `AesCryptoServiceProvider`. Maybe you're referencing .dlls specific to version 2 and that's why you're getting errors when changing to 4.

Comment: Change *Target Version* to 4 and remove references that are throwing errors. Add them again if needed using the *Add Reference* wizard.

Answer (score 5):

[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is a reserved keyword. Use a different identifier name or [`@var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-sharp-variable-name-do).

```
System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider @var;
```

---

This may not be the problem - you need to ensure that each project has a reference to `System.Core` the assembly containing `System.Security.Cryptography`.

You will also need to ensure that you are targeting a framework version that contains this class (.NET 3.5 and above) - this can be done in the project property pages.

Answer (score 1):

Are the references the same between both project?  Just open references and see.  I bet you are missing one.  However, you really should use a different variable name than var.  Also, can you post the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't name a variable `var` because it's a reserved word, use a different name, this will not cause an error :

`System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider _var;`

**Edit :**

`AesCryptoServiceProvider` is only supported in .Net framework 4 and 3.5 SP1, change the target framework and it will work and be sure to have `System.Security.Cryptography;` in that file.