# LINQ and ColumnAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, columnattribute

Can anyone please enlighten me why what the @_ means before the members of this object, as after 6 hours I am not any wiser. Many thanks

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="[_SessionID]", Storage="__SessionID", DbType="VarChar(100)")]
public string _SessionID
{
    get
    {
        return this.@__SessionID;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this.@__SessionID != value))
        {
            this.On_SessionIDChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this.@__SessionID = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("_SessionID");
            this.On_SessionIDChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254674/471214):

> It's just a way to allow declaring reserved keywords as vars.
>
> `void Foo(int @string)`

No special meaning.