# How to filter a dictionary to have items with unique values?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Please bear with me if you think I haven't done enough research before asking

**Problem**
Just came across a business requirement where we have to make sure the values in a dictionary are unique. i.e., We should filter a dictionary and the result of such filtering should have key value pairs with unique values.

BTW, it is a simple Dictionary with string values and string keys.  To clarify more, below are the **sample input and expected output values -**
sourceDictionary would have values like below (just for the sake of representation of data, not syntactically correct) -  {    {"Item1", "Item One"},  {"Item11", "Item One"}, {"Item2", "Item Two"}, {"Item22", "Item Two"}  }  for this input, filteredDictionary should look like below -  {    {"Item1", "Item One"},  {"Item2", "Item Two"}  }

**Solution I proposed that is working**

```
    var sourceDictionary = serviceAgent.GetSampleDictionary(); // Simplified for brevity  
    var filteredDictionary =  
        sourceDictionary.GroupBy(s => s.Value)  
            .Where(group => @group.Any())  
            .Select(g => g.First())  
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

**Question**
Am I making too much logic into it? OR, putting it in other words, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: what is the `@` in `@group.Any()` ? Is this a typo?

Comment: @Rotem "@" allows you to use a C# reserved word.

Comment: I believe it is a ReSharper stuff ... probably because it thinks group is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Thimmarasau - it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx

Comment: @Rotem - Got it.  Also, I just came across this thread that talks about using '@' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-sharp-variable-name-do

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the sample data more readable...but couldn't, owing to my lack of experience in authoring on stackoverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
.Where(group => @group.Any())
```

is unnecessary, as you won't get any empty groups anyway. (Also not sure what the '@' is for.)

Other than that, there's not really a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I agree. That Where clause is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Your method works, but it's not extremely readable. If you create your class this way:

```
class DictionaryValueComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> x, KeyValuePair<T1, T2> y)
    {
        return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> obj)
    {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can reduce your method to:

```
dictionary = dictionary.Distinct(new DictionaryValueComparer<int, string>()).
    ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Comment: I see your point Eve. I think I should try this as I use quite a few look up entities of type Dictionary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter May I ask how the constructor would help, since it compares only the keys?

Comment: +1, this is more efficient than the `GroupBy` and more compact at the point of calling (if you don't mind having the comparer class tucked away somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Linq extension method .Distinct()?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then, could not get the right predicate to use inside the Distinct call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's not a custom type(then you need to implement [`IEqualityComparer<YourType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and pass it to `Distinct`)

```
var distinctDict = sourceDictionary
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.Distinct());
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/3Lpd7C)

```
var sourceDictionary=new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
sourceDictionary.Add("A", new List<string>() { "A", "A", "B"});
sourceDictionary.Add("B", new List<string>() { "C", "D", "D" });

var distinctDict = sourceDictionary.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.Distinct());
foreach(var kv in distinctDict)
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Values:{1}", kv.Key, string.Join(",", kv.Value));
    // "A", "B" and "C", "D"
```

Comment: Have you not misunderstood the question? I thought the source dictionary `Value` type is not an enumerable, but that the OP wants no two keys in the dictionary to have the same value.

Comment: I apologize for missing the type info. Edited the question to indicate the types.

Comment: @Rotem: _"we have to make sure the values in a dictionary are unique. i.e., We should filter a dictionary and the result of such filtering should have key value pairs with **unique values**."_ Edit: htmm, yes, maybe i've understood the question in a different way ;)

Comment: Rotem is right. I basically want the resultant Dictionary to have unique keys(obviously :)) and unique values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understood something different from that sentence. Perhaps the OP should clarify, as the other answers and the OP's original code do somehing else.

Comment: @Rotem: I will not edit or delete it since others have answered the question in the way OP wants. But it might be helpful for someone who comes across this title.