# ASP.NET Core 5.0. Scaffolded controller variable names. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

So when i scaffold a controller for my Event model it builds the typical GET/POST controller page.

It seems like every instance of the variable "event" has an @ in front of it. If i try to remove the @ it doesn't recognize the word as a variable (even with var in front of the word). Im pretty new to coding and i havent seen this before, what is causing this?

See examples below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var @event = await _context.Events
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EventId == id);
            if (@event == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(@event);
        }
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EventId,Subject,Description,StartTime,EndTime,Theme,IsFullDay")] Event @event)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(@event);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(@event);
        }
```

Comment: how do you scaffold your controller? `event` is a special name (matching with the keyword `event`) so to make it valid, we need to prefix it with `@`. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-sharp-variable-name-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is a reserved word, if use it, you have to add `@` in front of it. You can change it to other variable.

Here is all the [Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/).